# Can anyone explain me what is 'Syria-bound' in the below headline?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms

> 'No survivors' as Syria-bound Russian jet crashes.

Can any one explain to me clearly? I tried to find what exactly that means but using Google, I could only find the news. Maybe my searched text was wrong.

Comment: a **Syria-bound** plane is a **plane bound for Syria**, that is, a plane that is (or was) going to Syria. Google for "[bound for](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bound+for)"

Answer (score 1):

**Bound** is one of those hard-working words with lots of uses and meanings. Interestingly, it seems that the same word has come from several different sources, including Old French and Old Norse.

This one is meaning 3 by the Oxford English Dictionary:

> **Bound 3**
>
> Going or ready to go towards a specified place
>
> *an express train **bound** for Edinburgh*
>
> *the three **moon-bound** astronauts*

The second example shows the same construction used in the OP's question.

In this case, then, we're talking about a plane that was **going to** Syria.

> 'No survivors' as Russian jet **going to Syria** crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Bound can mean to go or to plan to go, especially to a certain destination, as in being bound for New York or homeward-bound. Superman can "leap tall buildings in a single bound," but the word bound is usually about boundaries. When you're playing soccer or football, the ball goes "out of bounds."